# Filter Array of user objects by array of roles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, find

I have an array of user objects. 
I want to filter them based on the array of user roles.

```
filter = ['ROLE_SELLER', 'ROLE_BANK', 'ROLE_CPF', 'ROLE_SLA', 'ROLE_LDAU']
```

```js
const users = [{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "user1@test.com",
  "name": "User1",
  "roles": [{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
    "name": "Administrator"
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
    "name": "Seller"

   }
  ]
 }, {
  "id": 2,
  "email": "user2@test.com",
  "name": "User2",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 1,
   "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
   "name": "Administrator"
  }]
 }, {
  "id": 3,
  "email": "user3@test.com",
  "name": "User3",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 1,
   "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
   "name": "Administrator"
  }]
 }, {
  "id": 4,
  "email": "user4@test.com",
  "name": "User4",
  "roles": [{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
    "name": "Administrator"
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
    "name": "Seller"

   }
  ]
 }, {
  "id": 5,
  "email": "user5@test.com",
  "name": "User5",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 5,
   "code": "ROLE_LAWYER",
   "name": "Lawyer"

  }]
 }, {
  "id": 6,
  "email": "user6@test.com",
  "name": "User6",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 2,
   "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
   "name": "Seller"

  }]
 },
 {
  "id": 7,
  "email": "user7@test.com",
  "name": "User7",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 9,
   "code": "ROLE_SLA",
   "name": "sla"
  }]
 },
 {
  "id": 8,
  "email": "user8@test.com",
  "name": "User8",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 8,
   "code": "ROLE_BANK",
   "name": "Bank"

  }]
 },
 {
  "id": 9,
  "email": "user9@test.com",
  "name": "User9",
  "roles": [{
   "id": 7,
   "code": "ROLE_CPF",
   "name": "CPF"
  }]
 }
]
const filter = ['ROLE_SELLER', 'ROLE_BANK', 'ROLE_CPF', 'ROLE_SLA', 'ROLE_LDAU']

const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => !user.roles.find(role => filter.includes(role.id)))

console.log(filteredUsers)
```

Expected result

```
 [{
        "id": 1,
        "email": "user1@test.com",
        "name": "User1",
        "roles": [{
                "id": 1,
                "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
                "name": "Administrator"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
                "name": "Seller"

            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "user4@test.com",
        "name": "User4",
        "roles": [{
                "id": 1,
                "code": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR",
                "name": "Administrator"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
                "name": "Seller"

            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "email": "user6@test.com",
        "name": "User6",
        "roles": [{
            "id": 2,
            "code": "ROLE_SELLER",
            "name": "Seller"

        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "user7@test.com",
        "name": "User7",
        "roles": [{
            "id": 9,
            "code": "ROLE_SLA",
            "name": "sla"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "user8@test.com",
        "name": "User8",
        "roles": [{
            "id": 8,
            "code": "ROLE_BANK",
            "name": "Bank"

        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "user9@test.com",
        "name": "User9",
        "roles": [{
            "id": 7,
            "code": "ROLE_CPF",
            "name": "CPF"
        }]
    }
 ]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Updated the question with expected answer

Comment: You are comparing wrong property. You want to compare `code` not `id`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for flagging that. I tried code and realised that the response is what I expect. Please see the updated question

Comment: @charlietfl I realised that I was using a ! In front of the condition. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to image what result you want to receive....

You want to filter of users by array with possible roles, another worlds if user has one of roles of filter array you want to pass his to 'filteredUsers' array?

filter.includes(role.id) - I guess it is wrong, may be you want to
   filter by role.code?

Array.find() doesn't support Explorer 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Array.includes() - doesn't support Explorer too.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why that was happening was that you are trying to match the role id with the 'filter' array which contains the role code. From what i observed from the expected answer, you are looking for user who has any one of their role fits the filter. So do the following will filter by role code and with the expected result

```
const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
    return user.roles.map(role=>filter.includes(role.code)).includes(true)
})
```

this line of code basically map the filter to every role object to every user, if their role code is included in the filter it will add a true to the array(return array of map()) and for the filter function if the map() return array contains true then true(so basically a || for the whole array)